# Disavow example sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Since I am unfamiliar with the word "disavow" and am unsure as to how to properly use it, please tell me if the examples presented below are correct.

Disavow = to deny responsibility for or to refuse to acknowledge something.

1. When asked, he disavowed the spy operation to gather intelligence concerning the missile plan. (Does this mean he did not know about the operation (did not acknowledge it) and was not responsible for it?)
2. He disavowed his earlier actions (does this mean he refused to acknowledge his actions?)
3. The employee disavowed plans to undermine his superior's authority. (Does this mean he had no idea of the plans?)

And feel free to provide example sentences using this word to deepen my understanding of this word, thanks.

Comment: Check Lexico for example sentences. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disavow

Comment: Also [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/disavow) is good for examples

Answer (score 1):

As mention [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disavow) on lexico:

Disavow means:

> Deny any responsibility or support for.

Examples sentence:

> ‘he appears to be in denial of his own past, which he continually disavows’

---

> When asked, he disavowed the spy operation to gather intelligence concerning the missile plan.

Means his hiding and denying what plan he was in about some "spy operation".

> He disavowed his earlier actions.

Means his not admitting his earlier actions.

> The employee disavowed plans to undermine his superior's authority.

Similar to the first sentence, denying and not admitting that he planned to "undermine his superior's authority".